# How do i format my multichoice math exam questions?

Tags: math-mode, exam

Please, kindly help me with a latex code that will format my multichoice mathematics examination questions as follow:

The paper will be divided into two columns. The options to questions are four and should be labeled A,B,C and D.

(1)if the answers of the options are single characters or short, they are arranged horizontally in one paragraph
(2) if they are a bit longer and can't occupy one paragraph, they are arranged in two paragraphs as A.  B. on first paragraph and C. D. on second paragraph
(3) if at least one is too long such that it can occupy entire paragraph, the options are formatted and arranged vertically

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly provide code of your current trials. Also a screenshot or sketch of (1) to (3) might clarify further, what you want to achieve. (To some degree we are code-junkies here, but for the main part it's easier to provide concrete help with code.)

Comment: welcome, could this post be of use to you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187591/multiple-choice-questions-type-setting-querries